# MYSQL select query with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, select, left-join

I have 2 tables,

1. `prices (pcode, date, priceperweek)`

   - 1 record covers 1 week
2. `booked (pcode, date)`

   - 1 record = 1 day, because shortbreaks are available

And a form consists of 3 fields

1. startdate
2. flexibility (+/- 1/2/3 weeks)
3. duration (3 / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 / 14)).

The below query should be selecting prices & dates and checking to see if the selected start date appears in the prices table and that each day from the startdate doesn't appear in the bookings table.

```
SELECT SUM(priceperweek) AS `ppw`, prices.date AS `startdate`
FROM `prices` LEFT JOIN `booked` ON prices.pcode=booked.pcode
WHERE prices.pcode='A2CD59GH'
    AND (prices.date IN ('20131221', '20131228')
        AND booked.date NOT IN ('20131221', '20131222', '20131223',
        '20131224', '20131225', '20131226', '20131227', '20131228',
        '20131229', '20131230', '20131231', '20140101', '20140102',
        '20140103')
    )
    OR (prices.date IN ('20131214', '20131221')
        AND booked.date NOT IN ('20131214', '20131215', '20131216',
            '20131217',
            '20131218', '20131219', '20131220', '20131221', '20131222',
            '20131223', '20131224', '20131225', '20131226', '20131227')
    )
    OR (prices.date IN ('20131228', '20140104') AND booked.date NOT IN
        ('20131228', '20131229', '20131230', '20131231', '20140101',
        '20140102', '20140103', '20140104', '20140105', '20140106',
        '20140107', '20140108', '20140109', '20140110')
    )
GROUP BY prices.date
ORDER BY prices.date ASC
```

**VALUES GIVEN TO QUERY...**

- startdate = 20131221
- duration = 14
- property = A2CD59GH
- plusminus = 1

My problem is that this query returns records even if some of the dates in a range appear in the "bookings" table AND the ppw value is alot more than i would have expected.

The reason for using SUM(ppw) is when a duration of 14 is specified the price will sum both weeks together.

Thanks for any help on this

Comment: Maybe start with something simpler, and gradually build up complexity. Also, that LEFT JOIN renders as an INNER JOIN. Is that what you want?

Comment: Im looking to return the prices for the startdate(s) given where NO date in the duration appears in the booked table for that property. and if possible sum the prices if the duration is 14, othewise just return the priceperweek for each week and i can sum the overall price before displaying with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that the `startdate` will only be filtered from the results if *every single record* in the `booked` table for the given `pcode` falls within the booking period.  Obviously this won't be the case if the property has been booked on some other date.

I'd suggest performing an anti-join along the following lines:

```sql
SELECT   t.date, SUM(prices.priceperweek) FROM prices JOIN (
  SELECT   prices.date
  FROM     prices LEFT JOIN booked
              ON booked.pcode = prices.pcode
             AND booked.date BETWEEN prices.date
                                 AND prices.date + INTERVAL 14 DAY
  WHERE    booked.pcode IS NULL
       AND prices.pcode = 'A2CD59GH'
       AND prices.date BETWEEN '20131221' - INTERVAL 1 WEEK
                           AND '20131221' + INTERVAL 2 WEEK
) t ON prices.date BETWEEN t.date AND t.date + INTERVAL 13 DAY
GROUP BY t.date
```

Comment: Thanks @eggyal : That worked pretty well in returning only the records where any date in those ranges don't appear in the 'booked' table... but the value returned for SUM(prices.priceperweek) is far higher than it should be. Is there some GROUP BY element that should be added?

Comment: @DavidG: Some sample data might help to illustrate your problem.  Perhaps set up a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)?

Comment: @DavidG: So what's the problem?  You're booking the weeks commencing 2014-01-11 and 2014-01-04, each at a rate of £600/week for £1200 total.  As an aside, you really ought to use MySQL's [`DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/datetime.html) type to store your dates.

Comment: When i run that same query in PhpMyAdmin, im getting the results... 
date SUM(prices.priceperweek)
20140104 728544.00

Comment: @DavidG: Do you have rates in the `prices` table for every day of the week?  Or perhaps multiple different rates for the same property?

Comment: ...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/289f2/10, do you know why this is returning 0 records?

Comment: @DavidG: What result do you expect to see?  You're searching for a free fortnight starting between 5 April and 3 May.  Week of 13-18 April is booked, so that rules out anything before 19 April; 3-4 May are booked, so that rules out everything else.